How to load a Big Endian CSV into sheetjs?
I am trying to load a CSV file having an UTF-16BE format (with BOM) into a sheetjs workbook:
import { read } from 'xlsx';

const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
const wb = read(buffer, { cellDates: true });

What gets into wb is not what I'd expect: it does not detect the encoding correctly. The problem remains even if I add the codepage: 1201 option to read. If I convert the same file into LE, sheetjs parses it correctly.
What do I miss?
(My current workaround is to convert the buffer from BE to LE before calling read, but it is not an optimal solution.)

So since there are no answers so far, I share my workaround code snippet:
import { read, type WorkBook } from 'xlsx';

async function upload(file: File) {
    function swap(val: number) {
        return ((val & 0xff) << 8) | ((val >> 8) & 0xff);
    }

    let buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();

    // converting buffer from Big Endian to Little Endian (which xlsx can read flawlessly)
    if (file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith('.csv')) {
        let ui16 = new Uint16Array(buffer);
        if (ui16[0] === 0xfffe) for (let i = 0; i < ui16.length; i++) ui16[i] = swap(ui16[i]);
    }
    let wb = read(buffer, { cellDates: true }) as WorkBook; // Excel workbook

    ...
}

